# Formating codes

Tags: excel, vba

Formaiting codes of headers and footers doesn't work when a user uses another office language then english, the users is mostly using Swedish. For example this:

```
.CenterHeader = "&B&14" & Sheets("Source").Range("W1").Value2 & vbCr & "&13" & "PLC01"
```

Is there any solutions to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On a German system all is fine when `Application.PrintCommunication = True` is set to true - maybe this makes a difference?

Comment: It work fine then I do it with Application.PrintCommunication = True, strange, do you know why?
Thank you!

Comment: no - sorry - I always play with PrintCommunication when I get to header/footer stuff in Excel ...

Comment: My theory is that in order to know what to do with a header, it needs to know what a page is, and Excel does not have "pages" until it needs to print something.

Comment: Sounds likely, any suggestions howcome it work with english but not other language?

Comment: It may not be related to the language, as there are other regional settings as well. And maybe the person with the other computer also has a different printer, and maybe that makes a difference. IMO there are just too many variables to know for sure.